# Where to place Q_DECLARE_METATYPE statement when using header and source files?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using my custom `struct` within `QWizard` pages. Let's say a `struct` (or `class`) like so:

```
// foo.h

namespace nm{

struct Foo
{
    Foo();
    void bar();
};

}
```

I want to be able to `registerField` with a `Q_PROPERTY` of type `nm::Foo`, for example:

```
// within some QWizardPage class
Q_PROPERTY(nm::Foo foo READ getFoo WRITE setFoo)
```

I know that in order for me to use it, I have to declare it as Qt metatype:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(nm::Foo)
```

But I cannot figure out where to correctly place the above statement. I tried to place it at the end of `Foo.cpp`, but get a compilation error:

> path/QtCore/qglobal.h:738: error: static assertion failed: Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system. #define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)

If I place it at the end of header file while also having a source file, I get:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/stddef.h:149: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘typedef’
>    typedef PTRDIFF_TYPE ptrdiff_t;

If I move all the definitions to the `Foo.h` and use it as a header-only file, then if I place the statement at the end of the file (outside of the namespace), it works. However, my class definitions are kind of long, and I want my class definitions to be placed at the source file.

Is there any way I can use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` while having header and source files for my class and not a header-only file?

**EDIT (Solution):** I had to *fully define* my class, i.e., provide public default ctor, copy ctor and dtor. The final code looks like:

```
// somewhere in Foo.h
#include <QMetaType>

namespace nm{
struct Foo
{
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo& other);
    ~Foo();

    void bar();
};
} 

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(nm::Foo)
```

Comment: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` goes in the header file. There is an example here about namespaces: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html

Comment: Note that the documentation states ***If MyStruct is in a namespace, the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() macro has to be outside the namespace:***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) (emphasis is mine):

> This macro makes the type *Type* known to [QMetaType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html) **as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor**. It is needed to use the type Type as a custom type in [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html).
>
> This macro requires that *Type* is a **fully defined** type at the point where it is used.

That's why the header-only solution works, and AFAIK there is no way but providing a full definition of the type before declaring it as a metatype.